# Extension to mysqli class to combine mysqli_stmt functions

Tags: php, mysqli

Does anyone know a short (short is a key word in here) extension to mysqli class to prepare, bind_param, execute and close a connection with one function?

Comment: It would be a function that does exactly those steps and no more. What have you tried to do to solve this so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite good idea, save for closing connection.

However, there is a problem (not a big one though) with the returning result type. Sure, one can always return an array of rows and get a single row as `$row[0]` and a single field using `current($row[0])` - but it turns out to be quite inconvenient.

Also there is a problem with data types other than silly ints and strings.

Thus, it turns out that we need a class. So, here you go - a [class, which methods are the very functions you're asking for](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql).

Look at the examples:

```
$db   = new safeMysql();

$name = $db->getOne('SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = ?i', $_GET['id']);
$data = $db->getInd('id','SELECT * FROM ?n WHERE id IN (?a)', $table, array(1,2));
$data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM ?n WHERE mod=?s LIMIT ?i", $table, $mod, $limit);
```

these methods do exactly what you ask: take your variables, bind them into query and returns a result (if any).

Comment: Thanks! I like this class, it's light and has all the needed functionality.

Comment: Please note that it doesn't actually use bind_param but just format your data properly and insert it into query. It is equally safe as native prepared statement but more convenient